# Rails, where function in class methods vs where function in instance methods

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am making a social networking app in Ruby on Rails and I saw an interesting behaviour when I use the where method inside and class method like in the Micropost model, it works without specifying the class in front of it ( something like "Micropost.where()")

```
    class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :content
      belongs_to :user

      validates :user_id, presence: true
      validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }

      default_scope order: "microposts.created_at DESC"

      def self.from_users_followed_by(user)
        followed_user_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                             WHERE follower_id = :user_id"
        where("user_id IN (#{followed_user_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id", 
               user_id: user.id )
      end  
    end
```

But when I'm using it in a instance method like below it needs to know the name of the model.

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      ...
      ...
      def friends()
        sql_direct_friends   = "SELECT friend_id FROM friendships
                                WHERE approved = :true_value AND user_id = :user_id"
        sql_indirect_friends = "SELECT user_id FROM friendships
                                WHERE approved = :true_value AND friend_id = :user_id"                       
        User.where("id IN (#{sql_direct_friends}) OR id IN (#{sql_indirect_friends})", user_id: id, true_value: true)
      end  
    end
```

then if I use "where" instead of "User.where" then I'll get an error like this:

```
  NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for #<User:0x00000004b908f8>
```

Why is that happening? Does the where method inside the friends() method thinks I'm using it as an instance method on the current object (self.friends())?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Inside an instance method, `where` is being sent to the User object; however, only the User *class* knows how to respond to `where`.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby method call is always sent to the current `self`.
You can even print `self` inside your methods and see what it will display.

`self` will be a class inside `def self.from_users_followed_by` and will be an instance of a class inside `def friends`.

No surprise that a message 'where' (in Ruby calling a method actually means sending a message to an object) is not recognized by a `self` in your `friends()` method.